# Blender 2.8 Selection issue in Edit mode

Tags: selection-tools, wireframe

Problem with selecting multiple vertices/edges in edit mode. When i want to select vertices one by one or using box select/ lasso select etc. blender behaves like in wireframe or x-ray mode. It grabs vertices from backside of the mesh. This issue i have since 2.8 beta and it still here in 2.81 alpha. The same problem in stable version. May be here is some feature that could turn off this or this is a strange behavior of 2.8?

[image: animated gif of the selection problem]

Comment: in the future please use the [edit] link below your question to add more info, instead of the comments.

Comment: I see that you tried to add it in the question. Yah, SE strips out all script elements like that. Best thing to do is use the built it image upload tools.

Comment: @David thanks for explaining. I could not use the built in feature because of size, so i tried to do in another way.